# Problem with one node using Touch XML

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How to parse only one node with Touch XML

```
<Link> http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss</Link>
```

http://rssreader.web44.net/rsslink.xml

My ObjC code

```
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

    // Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

    // Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"Link" error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with TouchXML, but I have found the next example:

```
NSArray *root = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Link"  error:nil]; 
CXMLElement Link = [root objectAtIndex:0];
```

See if it helps...

**EDIT**:

Maybe you should use:

```
NSArray *root = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//" error:nil];
```